# Set multi select for select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a select tag which i am generating by looping the records and creating options manually. Here is the code:

```
    <%= f.select (:book_id_eq_any) do %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, "Choose your option", value: "", disabled: '', selected: '') %>
      <% @books.each do |book| %>
        <%= content_tag(:option, book.book_title, value: book.id) %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

When i add {multiple: true}, it does not work. Can anyone give me hint about it. Thanks

Comment: what 'does not work' about it? does it give you an error, is it ignoring the flag and just making it a single select, etc. you dont have `multiple: true` set anywhere in the example. can you display the code you're using when you set that property

Comment: Strong parameters set to accept an array?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in select form helper:

```
<%= f.collection_select :book_id_eq_any, @books, :id, :book_title, { include_blank: "Choose your option" }, { multiple: true } %>
```